# How to add action to UINavigationItem?

Tags: swift, xcode, navigation, navigationbar

I need to create dynamically `Navigation Bar` and set `Cancel` button in left side.

There is code how I try to do it

```
var navBar: UINavigationBar = UINavigationBar()
func setNavBarToTheView() {
    navBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 80.0)
    navBar.backgroundColor = (UIColor.black)

    let navTitle = UINavigationItem(title: "Camera")
    let navCancel = UINavigationItem(title: "Cancel")

    navBar.setItems([navCancel, navTitle], animated: true)
    view.addSubview(navBar)
}
```

But how I could to add action listener to `Cancel` button??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UINavigationItem` is a model object storing information about buttons for a screen.

What you need is one `UINavigationItem` with `leftBarButtonItem` and `rightBarButtonItem` set.

```
let item = UINavigationItem(title: "Title")
item.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title:"Cancel",
                                         style:.plain,
                                         target:self,
                                         action:#selector(cancelTapped))

navBar.setItems([item], animated: true)
```